# C++ (Ardouino) int in ASCII String

Tags: arduino, int, ascii

How can I convert an integer(example 68) in a String(should be "D")?

I've already tried `char c = (char)i;` , but I'm completly noob at C++

Answer (score 0):

You are converting an int to a ASCII char right? This should work

You can simply cast it.

1. int a = 68;
2. char D = static_cast(a);

You are converting an int to a ASCII char right? This should work